# Runtime error with arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, runtime, runtime-error

Hi I've recently worked with DirectX9 and I've came across this error. Although it has nothing to do with DirectX. Here is what I have.

```
struct D3DVertex
{
    float x, y, z;
    DWORD Color;
};


int main()
{
    D3DVertex *TestShape = new D3DVertex();

        TestShape[0].x = 0.0f;
        TestShape[0].y = 2.0f;
        TestShape[0].z = 0.5f;
        TestShape[0].Color = 0xffffffff;

        TestShape[1].x = -2.0f;
        TestShape[1].y = -2.0f;
        TestShape[1].z = 0.5f;
        TestShape[1].Color = 0xffffffff;

        TestShape[2].x = 2.0f;
        TestShape[2].y = -2.0f;
        TestShape[2].z = 0.5f;
        TestShape[2].Color = 0xffffffff;

return 0;
}
```

When I run this it gives me a runtime error which says this.

```
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in x.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in x.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while x.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information.
```

but when I take this line away `TestShape[2].z = 0.5f;` the error goes away.
Why does this happen and how could I fix it. Please help.

Comment: you created a single object and accessing like an array. Thats is the problem. use this for creating a array(size 3) of objects D3DVertex *TestShape = new D3DVertex[3];

Comment: How could I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating a single object in memory:

```
D3DVertex *TestShape = new D3DVertex();
```

and then you're accessing it like it was an array

```
TestShape[x] ...
```

That's what the problem is, you don't have an array.  You have a single object.

Create an array:

```
D3DVertex *TestShape = new D3DVertex[3];
```

Now you have 3 objects of type `D3DVertex`.

The important point to remember is that pointers are NOT arrays.  The only time you will get a pointer is when the array has *decayed* into a pointer when you passed it as an argument to a function. Then you get a pointer to the first element in the array.

Even better would be, to use a `std::vector<D3DVertex> TestShape;` and not worry about dealing with pointers.

```
D3DVertex foo; //create object.

TestShape.push_back(foo); //add it to your vector.
```

You can access your vector using `operator[]` for unchecked access or `at(index)` for bounds checked access

```
D3DVertex f = TestShape[0]; //Get element zero from TestShape.
```

If you want to go through the vector and look at each element:

```
for (std::vector<D3DVector>::iterator it = TestShape.begin(); it != TestShape.end(); ++it) // loop through all elements of TestShape.
{
     D3DVector vec = *it; //contents of iterator are accessed by dereferencing it
     (*it).f = 0; //assign to contents of element in vector.
}
```

Comment: Okay, I'm starting to understand but if I created a vector how could I take out only the array from the vector?

Comment: Okay that tells me how to get an element from the vector but what if I wanted to return a whole array from the vector. Like what if I had more than a 1000 elements in an array and I didn't know how much I actually had (I know you how can you find out).

Comment: I am trying to make this work.
D3DVertex f[];
f[0].x = ?;
but obviously I need a constant for the f[] but what if i was reading from a file and i wanted to put that value in the f[]

Comment: @Efex see amend to my answer

Comment: okay so if I was to use this function 'memcpy' and i had a vector with 10 elements in it vector<D3DVertex> thisx;
could I just do this memcpy(?, thisx, ?)

Comment: @Efex why would you use `memcpy`?

Comment: in DirectX9 when your making vertex buffers you need to use it to load vertices in memory, do you have a skype? might be easier to solve it there

Comment: @Efex except on Skype it won't help future visitors on Stack Overflow. So no.

Comment: memcpy works fine, i tested it on my program and every worked